# How can I make incremental nandroid backups?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, nandroid

I'm using PhilZ Touch 6.57.9 with ClockworkMod 6.0.5.1 on a MT6592 device. I'm creating backups every once in a while from my phone to my 16-GB SD card.

These SD cards tend to get full pretty fast, so I'm wondering if there's a way to create incremental backups. It would be nice if it's possible using PhilZ .

Comment: Does it take too long for the device to make full backup? Because I do not see benefit in having incremental backup.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to have multiple backups without moving them to my PC every so many weeks.

Comment: Are you familiar with sh/bash scripting? You can use `find` to list all the files/directories which have changed or created since last backup time and them copy them into a tar file. Put that script into a flashable zip and there you go. Incremental backups for you.